# Raspberry PI3 RTC problems with ntpd on jessie

Tags: pi-3, boot, jessie-lite, ntp, rtc

i am looking for a solution that can prefer NTP, updating the RTC when possible, and then fall back to the RTC when no network is available.

- it seems that NTP do this job and when the ntp is running it syncs RPI's time also the hwclock to the ntpserver time?
- during boot up system date acts weird! some time works fime, some times sync with rtc, some time go back to 1999 ,....
  any help in this regard?

by the way:
i have sussessfully done these stuff:

- add an RTC to raspberry pi (as we know adding RTC is quite diferent thing on Raspbian Jessie or Raspbian Wheezy.) https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/set-rtc-time
- setting raspberry time to ntp servers is also not that much
  difficult!
- ntpd is working ok and syncs the rpi to an ntp server
- i can easily sync rtc to/from system using hwclock -s or -w

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? You have told us lots of things you haven't done, or imagine don't work , but not **what you have actually done**

Comment: i have added RTC to RPI3 and it works, i also installed ntpd daemon and it works fine. the problem starts when the pi boots or when i plug the power; time goes back to 1999 meanwhile rtc has kept the time when i read it with hwclock -r. i checked the boot sequence, when the RPI boots the time is OK (a simple script show time on boot on LCD) but as soon as ntp is started the time goes back to 1999

Comment: There was no need to "installed ntpd daemon". **Why?** it would have been present. You still haven't said **what you have actually done** "added RTC" which? how? **DO NOT PUT DETAIL IN Comments** paste into your question. **DO NOT** say "is OK", if you actually want help put actual data in the question.